# Hash map in ruby is storing key-value pair automatically

Tags: ruby, data-structures, hash

This is generally a way to create a `Hash Map` in Ruby

```
colors = {

"red" => 2, 
"blue" => 3

}
```

But in below code, where did Key and its corresponding value is specified, like it was done in "colors" hash.

```
puts "enter a string"
text = gets.chomp
words=text.split
frequencies = Hash.new(0)
words.each {|word| frequencies [word] +=1}
frequencies = frequencies.sort_by do |wordy, wcounty|
    wordy
end
puts frequencies
```

Is it done in each loop or in line next to it where "frequencies" new value is assigned as a loop, if Yes , how?

I am new to `Ruby` but I have little knowledge of `JAVA`, so its difficult for me to understand.

Comment: Hint: how can you get the value in `colors` with the key `"blue"`?

Comment: why did you delete the answer, was it incorrect?

Comment: It's not wrong, but I thought what you don't understand is the default value part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at this line:

```
words.each {|word| frequencies [word] +=1}
```

you can think of this this code like this (just for example, this is a not rubyish way to write it):

```
i=1
words.each do |word|
  frequencies [word] = i
  i = i +1
end
```

The key is the word and its corresponding value you are assigning to i.  In case you are wondering, the do/end key values is the same as {}. You use it when the code inside the iterator span multiple lines.

Hope it helps

Comment: Right lucas, but to assign a key to a value we use `=>`, the way we used in "colors" but in other code `=` is used. which is used to assign values. Isnt that confusing?

Comment: Hi Paul. Not really, there are two ways of doing it. You can create a hash like this: **colors = { "red" => 2, "blue => 3}** or you can create a new hash and assign values after, like you would do with an array: **color = {}; color["red"]=2;color["blue"]=3**